# &apos; displayed in HTML file opened in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, html, html5

I think I'm missing something here as Google isn't finding **anything** about this...

I have an HTML5 file, saved in UTF-8 with a .htm extension:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&apos;Cell 1&apos;</td>
      <td>&quot;Cell 2&quot;</td>
      <td>Signed &amp; delivered</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</body></html>
```

When I open this file in Excel [2019 MSO (Version 2205 Build 16.0.15225.20028) 32-bit], I get this:

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| &apos;Cell 1&apos; | "Cell 2" | Signed & delivered |

Character entities are properly 'translated' except for `&apos;`

Granted, `&apos;` wasn't an official entity in HTML4, but it was added in HTML5.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia
[Apostrophe - Entering apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Entering_apostrophes)
says this :

> XML (and hence XHTML) defines an `&apos;` character entity reference for the ASCII typewriter apostrophe. `&apos;` is officially supported in HTML since HTML 5. It is not defined in HTML 4 despite all the other predefined character entities from XML being defined. If it cannot be entered literally in HTML, a numeric character reference could be used instead, such as `&#x27;` or `&#39;`.

It seems you have just proved that Excel has not (yet) advanced to HTML5,
or not fully.

In the meantime, you could use `&#39;` instead of `&apos;` to work as
expected in Excel.